# Npm install not working in windows after node upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm-install, node-modules

Last night I have upgraded my Node.JS and after that my npm install stopped working. I have uninstall Node and reinstalled it again but that is of no use. I am using Windows 8.1, Node - 8.9.4 and NPM - 3.3.12. Below is the error I am getting while running npm install.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Subrata\\AppData
\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\1-NodeJSTest\CoreNodeJSTest\SimpleSessionTest\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: update your  npm

Answer (score 0):

Your NPM is probably out of date. Try typing `npm install -g npm` to upgrade it, then close your command prompt and open another one, and try to do the `npm install` again. If that doesn't work, run `node --version` and `npm --version` and post the results in a comment here.

Comment: npm install -g npm didn't work for me. So I uninstalled the node and installed NVM and through NVM installed it again. I also deleted NodeJS folder from Program Files and NPM folder from user location before installing through NVM. Thanks for your suggestion.